# How to create a menu from a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have got a task to create a horizontal menu from json object.My json file is

```
var data = [
{

    "menu":[
        {
            "MenuId":1,
            "MenuName":"Home",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":1,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":2,
            "MenuName":"New Transaction",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":2,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":3,
            "MenuName":"Portfolio",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":3,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":4,
            "MenuName":"Analytics",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":4,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":5,
            "MenuName":"Instructions",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":5,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":6,
            "MenuName":"Data Upload",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":6,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":{
            }
        },
        {
            "MenuId":7,
            "MenuName":"Administration",
            "MenuLink":null,
            "Action":null,
            "Controller":null,
            "ParentID":null,
            "SortOrder":7,
            "ModuleId":null,
            "Menus":[
                {
                    "MenuId":8,
                    "MenuName":"Masters",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":7,
                    "SortOrder":1,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":[
                        {
                            "MenuId":10,
                            "MenuName":"Currency",
                            "MenuLink":"/Currencies/Index",
                            "Action":"Index",
                            "Controller":"Currencies",
                            "ParentID":8,
                            "SortOrder":1,
                            "ModuleId":null,
                            "Menus":{
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "MenuId":11,
                            "MenuName":"Country",
                            "MenuLink":"/Countries/Index",
                            "Action":"Index",
                            "Controller":"Countries",
                            "ParentID":8,
                            "SortOrder":2,
                            "ModuleId":null,
                            "Menus":{
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "MenuId":9,
                    "MenuName":"User Management",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":7,
                    "SortOrder":2,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":{
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
];
```

How can i create a horizontal menu from this  json file? Please help me too write javascript for this json data.I created an example here http://jsfiddle.net/s4DeS/

Comment: It looks like you already have a solution in your JSFiddle example. Also I think the code you put above is not technically JSON but a bunch of nested array- and object-literals. Are you asking for help with importing and parsing the JSON or do you just want to know how to loop through the above arrays/objects and create a menu?

Comment: i want to know how the arrays and objects are working.. i am new in json..

Comment: JSON is just data store format, no more. Your question is "how javascript work"

Comment: yes.. i want to know how the javascript comes?

Comment: Arrays and Objects don't have anything to do with JSON. JSON == "`An intrinsic object that provides functions to convert JavaScript values to and from the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format. The JSON.stringify function serializes a JavaScript value to JSON text. The JSON.parse function deserializes JSON text to produce a JavaScript value."` Citated from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836458%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). You're handling very regular JS objects here.

Comment: I've created what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/9NAJe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/XecTZ/

```
        var data = [{
            "menu":[
                {
                    "MenuId":1,
                    "MenuName":"Home",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":null,
                    "SortOrder":1,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":{
                    }
                },
                {
                    "MenuId":2,
                    "MenuName":"New Transaction",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":null,
                    "SortOrder":2,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":{
                    }
                },
                {
                    "MenuId":3,
                    "MenuName":"Portfolio",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":null,
                    "SortOrder":3,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":{
                    }
                },
                {
                    "MenuId":4,
                    "MenuName":"Analytics",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":null,
                    "SortOrder":4,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":{
                    }
                },
                {
                    "MenuId":5,
                    "MenuName":"Instructions",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":null,
                    "SortOrder":5,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":{
                    }
                },
                {
                    "MenuId":6,
                    "MenuName":"Data Upload",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":null,
                    "SortOrder":6,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":{
                    }
                },
                {
                    "MenuId":7,
                    "MenuName":"Administration",
                    "MenuLink":null,
                    "Action":null,
                    "Controller":null,
                    "ParentID":null,
                    "SortOrder":7,
                    "ModuleId":null,
                    "Menus":[
                        {
                            "MenuId":8,
                            "MenuName":"Masters",
                            "MenuLink":null,
                            "Action":null,
                            "Controller":null,
                            "ParentID":7,
                            "SortOrder":1,
                            "ModuleId":null,
                            "Menus":[
                                {
                                    "MenuId":10,
                                    "MenuName":"Currency",
                                    "MenuLink":"/Currencies/Index",
                                    "Action":"Index",
                                    "Controller":"Currencies",
                                    "ParentID":8,
                                    "SortOrder":1,
                                    "ModuleId":null,
                                    "Menus":{
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "MenuId":11,
                                    "MenuName":"Country",
                                    "MenuLink":"/Countries/Index",
                                    "Action":"Index",
                                    "Controller":"Countries",
                                    "ParentID":8,
                                    "SortOrder":2,
                                    "ModuleId":null,
                                    "Menus":{
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "MenuId":9,
                            "MenuName":"User Management",
                            "MenuLink":null,
                            "Action":null,
                            "Controller":null,
                            "ParentID":7,
                            "SortOrder":2,
                            "ModuleId":null,
                            "Menus":{
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        ];

        for(var i = 0, j = data[0].menu.length; i<j; i++) {
            var root_menu = data[0].menu[i];
            if(root_menu.hasOwnProperty("MenuId")) {
                $("#menu").append("<li>" + root_menu.MenuName + "</li>");
                if(root_menu.hasOwnProperty("Menus") && root_menu.Menus.length > 0) {
                    $("#menu").append("<li><ul id='menu_" + root_menu.MenuId + "'>");
                    for(var n = 0, m = root_menu.Menus.length; n<m; n++) {
                        var sub_menu = root_menu.Menus[n];
                        if(sub_menu.hasOwnProperty("MenuId")) {
                            $("#menu_" + root_menu.MenuId).append("<li>" + sub_menu.MenuName + "</li>");

/* e.t.c but DONT REPEAT YOURSELF */
/* but if there is 50 levels- what a u going to do? */
/* look at recursive way */

                        }
                    }
                    $("#menu").append("</li></ul>");
                }
            }
        }
```

U have to add 1,2,3 level menu if u need this, but best practise (DRY) to write recursive function.

Comment: @FSou1-Do you know about responsive design?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through data:

```
var a = data[0].menu;
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    // Create menu components here
    var menuId = a[i].MenuId;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Did you noticed, there's a `"Menus: {};` for sub-menus in each menu object...

Answer (score 0):

i would say try it with jquery like this .

```
var Data = // your json object .

var x = eval('('+Data+')');
$.each(x,function(entryIndex, entry){
 var menuId  = entry['menu']['menuId']; 
// and so on all the elements .
});
```

i dont know if this will work for you . but its worth a try .

Comment: but did you check what is the output in menuId . If you can try once and tell me may be i can help you out .

Comment: you can check it on http://jsfiddle.net/s4DeS/..  I want the output like this. How can i write a script for this?